# Outlet that i want to move. 2 cables in the box. Neutrals from each cable attached but only one hot attached

Tags: receptacle

Want to be sure if the second hot isn't attached then there is no power going downstream. I was pretty sure that the outlet was at the end of the line so I was surprised to find the second cable in the box. The outlet is farthest away from the panel on that circuit.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Where does that second cable lead?

Comment: Is the power continuing past the outlet if only the neutral and ground wires are attached to the outlet?